# I want to calculate score of my survey section wise using JS/HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating one survey using JS/HTML and want to calculate score and % of survey section wise like one section is having 3 question and other section is having 4 question so score and % should be calculated on that way.I am giving the code which i have created but it is only working for one section.
form.html

```js
function displayRadioValue() {

  var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  let total = 0
  let res = ''
  let totalNumQuestions = 0
  for (i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {

    if (ele[i].type = "radio") {

      if (ele[i].checked) {
        totalNumQuestions++
        total += parseFloat(ele[i].value)

        res += ele[i].name + " Value: " + ele[i].value + "<br>";
      }
    }



  }
  res += "Total: " + total + "<br>"
  res += "Percentage: " + ((total / (totalNumQuestions * 3)) *
    100).toFixed(2) + "%"

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = res
}
`
```

```html
<p>
  Select a radio button and click on Submit.
</p>
<h2>Section 1</h2>
<h3>question 1: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="3">3

<br> question 2:
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="3">3

<br> question 3:
<input type="radio" name="question3" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="question3" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question3" value="3">3

<br>

<h2>Section 2</h2>
<h3>question 1: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="3">3

<br> question 2:
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="3">3
<br> question 3:
<input type="radio" name="question3" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="question3" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question3" value="3">3
<br> question 4:
<input type="radio" name="question4" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="question4" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question4" value="3">3

<button type="button" onclick="displayRadioValue()"> 
        Submit 
    </button>

<br>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Two things here, fix the HTML issue "Unexpected end of input" and are you sure the name attribute's value remain same across sections?

Comment: @Asutosh i haven't put the actual code as it is confidential i changed the code and put the simple one so may be there are some error ..... i just want to know the logic...how can i get the result properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is fully working code for you. First you need to wrap `each` section separately in `div` so we can call them `separately` as well for `calculation`

You can use `querySelecterAll` method and use `forEach` to get all the `checked` value of each sections `radio` buttons **per section**.

Store each sections `total` and `percentage` separately to display below the `section`.

To get the percentage we need to divide the total with `totalQuestions` and then mulitple by 100 and use `toFixed()` function to get the actual `percentage` in `decimals`.

There were few `HTML` fixes needed in your HTML as well which i have fixed as well.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
function displayRadioValue() {
  let section1 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-1 > input[type="radio"]')
  let section2 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-2 > input[type="radio"]')
  let section1Total = 0
  let section2Total = 0
  let section1Question = 0
  let section2Question = 0
  let section1Res = document.querySelector('.section-1-results')
  let section2Res = document.querySelector('.section-2-results')
  let result1 = ''
  let result2 = ''

  //Section 1
  section1.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section2Question++
      section1Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  //Section 2
  section2.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section1Question++
      section2Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  //Section 1
  result1 += "<b>Results:</b><br>"
  result1 += "Total: " + section1Total + "<br>"
  result1 += "Percentage: " + ((section1Total / (section2Question * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2) + "%"
  section1Res.innerHTML = result1

  //Section 2
  result2 += "<b>Results:</b><br>"
  result2 += "Total: " + section2Total + "<br>"
  result2 += "Percentage: " + ((section2Total / (section2Question * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2) + "%"
  section2Res.innerHTML = result2

}
```

```html
<p>
  Select a radio button and click on Submit.
</p>
<div class="section-1">

  <h2>Section 1</h2>
  question 1:
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="3">3

  <br> question 2:
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="3">3

  <br> question 3:
  <input type="radio" name="question3" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question3" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question3" value="3">3

</div>
<br>
<div class="section-1-results"></div>

<div class="section-2">

  <h2>Section 2</h2>
  question 1:
  <input type="radio" name="question4" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question4" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question4" value="3">3

  <br> question 2:
  <input type="radio" name="question5" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question5" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question5" value="3">3
  <br> question 3:
  <input type="radio" name="question6" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question6" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question6" value="3">3
  <br> question 4:
  <input type="radio" name="question7" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question7" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question7" value="3">3
</div>
<br>

<div class="section-2-results"></div>

<br>

<button type="button" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
  Submit
</button>
```

Comment: i accepetd your answer.

Comment: @jugal Thank you. I provided you the exact working solution as you wanted. I appreciate it!

Comment: Is it possible if i can show the result in new page ? Like after submitting new page open and i will able to see the result section wise ...

Comment: @jugal Yes! It is possible. But then there is a `alot` more work involved in that. That will be totally seperate question. Since we need to store all value in some kind of `arrays` and then ` loop` through that array on the second page to show the results section wise.

Comment: Can i show this result in table format in same page ?

Comment: @jugal yes you can do that as well. But the table needs to be generated dynamically on the same page via JAVAScript when you click submit button. Also you need to style your table to make it look nice.

Answer (score -2):

You have added duplicate group name on radio input in your example, I have removed all the minor issues in your code.

Here is the working example:

```js
var result = {};
var maxOptions = 3;
function displayRadioValue() { 
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ""; 
        var section = document.querySelectorAll('section');
        for(i = 0; i < section.length; i++) {
          result[section[i].id] = {
          totalChecked: 0,
          totalQuestions:0, 
          percent: 0
          };
          var ele = section[i].querySelectorAll('input');
          result[section[i].id].totalQuestions = ele.length/maxOptions;
          for(j = 0; j < ele.length; j++) { 
              if(ele[j].type === "radio" && ele[j].checked) {
                    result[section[i].id].totalChecked++;
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += ele[j].name + " Value: " + ele[j].value + "<br>";
              } 
          }
          result[section[i].id].percent = ((result[section[i].id].totalChecked/result[section[i].id].totalQuestions)*100).toFixed(2)+"%";
        }
        
        console.log(result);
    }
```

```html
<p> 
    Select a radio button and click on Submit. 
</p> 
<section id="section1">
<h2>Section 1</h2>  
<h3>question 1: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="section1_question1" value="1">1 
<input type="radio" name="section1_question1" value="2">2 
<input type="radio" name="section1_question1" value="3">3 
  
<br> 
  
<h3>question 2:</h3>
<input type="radio" name="section1_question2" value="1">1 
<input type="radio" name="section1_question2" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="section1_question2" value="3">3

<br>
<h3>question 3:</h3>
<input type="radio" name="section1_question3" value="1">1 
<input type="radio" name="section1_question3" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="section1_question3" value="3">3
</section>
<br> 

<section id="section2">
<h2>Section 2</h2>  
<h3>question 1: </h3>
<input type="radio" name="section2_question1" value="1">1 
<input type="radio" name="section2_question1" value="2">2 
<input type="radio" name="section2_question1" value="3">3 
  
<br> 
  
<h3>question 2:</h3>
<input type="radio" name="section2_question2" value="1">1 
<input type="radio" name="section2_question2" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="section2_question2" value="3">3
<br>
<h3>question 3:</h3>
<input type="radio" name="section2_question3" value="1">1 
<input type="radio" name="section2_question3" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="section2_question3" value="3">3
<br>
<h3>question 4:</h3>
<input type="radio" name="section2_question4" value="1">1 
<input type="radio" name="section2_question4" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="section2_question4" value="3">3
</section>
<button type="button" onclick="displayRadioValue()"> 
    Submit 
</button> 
<br> 
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I have already updated my code..... do you have answer?

Comment: @jugal check above example snippet, if this works for you. I have already reformed your code in above example.

Comment: not able to see where did you change in my code (where i have calculated score and %)

Comment: @jugal see my answer to your question, run the example & see if it works for you.

Comment: No it's not the answer .... even in your code you havn't put the logic which i have put to calculate the score and %

Comment: @jugal got it, you have updated your function, I have edited the answer for you, now it's working as expected. Run answer snippet to see the results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220195/discussion-between-yogendra-chauhan-and-jugal).

Comment: @YogendraChauhan Why are you downvoting my answer ? any reason please comment as well if you are downvoting a working answer

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Your answer is not correct, run your example & see the results. it's showing 0 in result even after i checked 2 or more radio input. You are also compelling the owner to check your answer as correct. This is not accepted to you with the reputation you have.

Comment: @YogendraChauhan  check the answer again and check the expected output OP wanted for each section. Let me know. Its working for EACH section. You need to select radio from EACH section. that what OP wanted NOT if you select only two radio buttons.

Comment: @YogendraChauhan Remember the word `EACH section` results. so if you do not select any thing in section offcourse you will get 0.

Comment: Both of yours ans are helpful but i can choose only one so i have choosen the closest one i have voted for both of you .... sorry if i hurt anyone... but i can choose only one.... thanks for helping me out

Comment: @YogendraChauhan That is what OP said => Read it carefully for your own sake => *calculate score and % of survey section wise like one section is having 3 question and other section is having 4 question so score and % should be calculated on that way.*